# How do I export a Keynote Presentation to PDF while embedding the font

Tags: pdf, keynote, font

It seems like the export to PDF option currently exists on Keynote (version '09) does not embed the font I use.

What are my options besides buying Adobe Acrobat Professional?

Comment: Without adobe it is going to be difficult.

Comment: apparently, even with adobe. I just downloaded the pro - trial version and yet, it doesn't seemed to embed the font. May you help me with that then

Comment: Keynote pdf export normally does embed fonts, so if you can't do it with yours, probably the font is the problem.  What is it? You may just have to use something else.

Comment: the font is franchise http://www.dafont.com/franchise.font

Comment: I downloaded the font, made a keynote slide with it, export to pdf (best quality), and opened with Adobe Reader.  File > Properties > Fonts says the doc has an embedded subset of Franchise Bold.  Do you get a different result with Adobe Reader File > Properties?

Comment: I do see this, as you do. However, I send it to my phone, and open it, and there are other fonts at there. I guess this is the phone's issue rather than PDF's. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I sent my test to my ipod and it displays exactly as it should, both in Mail and Adobe Reader and iBooks.  What are you reading it with on your iphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested the font you mention in exporting pdf (best quality) from keynote and it is both embedded and displays correctly on my iOS devices using Adobe Reader or iBooks to open the file.  It should work for you as well.  If not, feel free to send me an example of your pdf for testing (tom at bluesky dot org).